# Add method to groovy.util.logging.Slf4j annotation?

Tags: groovy, slf4j

I'd like to know if it's possible to use Groovy to dynamically add a new logging method to [`groovy.util.logging.Slf4j`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/logging/Slf4j.html), `log.opsAlert(Exception)` where:

```
void opsAlert(Exception exc) {
    log.error("OPS_ALERT: ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exc)}")
}
```

The idea here is that calling `log.opsAlert(exc)` will do the same as `log.error(exc)` but it prepends the string "*OPS_ALERT:*" to each stack trace. My hope is to use this inside my log aggregator to notify ops of special exceptions that require immediate attention.

Full example of what I'm hoping for:

```
package myapp.whatever

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class FizzBuzz {
    void doSomething() {
        // lots of code...

        try {
            // more code...
        } catch(FizzException fizzExc) {
            log.opsAlert(fizzExc)
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add such a method. Here's one way to do it.

## Add a decorator

Start out with a decorator that adds the method.

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
import groovy.transforms.TupleConstructor
import groovy.lang.Delegate

@TupleConstructor
class OpsAlertDecorator {

    @Delegate Logger log

    void opsAlert(Exception exc) {
        error("OPS_ALERT: ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exc)}")
    }

}
```

In this example the Logger is `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` I'm not sure what type of logger @Slf4j adds, but whatever it is, that's what the delegate needs to be set to. In other words, `@Delegate def log` will not work.

## Use the decorator

Then you can use the decorator when you need it.

```
@Slf4j(value='realLogger')
class FizzBuzz {
    def log

    def FizzBuzz() {
        log = new OpsAlertDecorator(realLogger)
    }

    void doSomething() {
        // lots of code...

        try {
            // more code...
        } catch(FizzException fizzExc) {
            log.opsAlert(fizzExc)
        }
    }
}
```